# Sort ArrayList of objects by field java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have this Student.class. I add some studens to an ArrayList and i sort the list by student grade. If two students happen to have the same grades, i want to sort those two by their names but i do not know how.

```
public class Student implements Comparator<Student>, Comparable<Student> {

private String name;
private int grade;

public Student(String name, int grade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
}

public Student() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(int grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    return (this.name).compareTo(o.name);
}

@Override
public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
    return o1.grade - o2.grade;
}



public class StudentMain {

protected static List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

private static void loadStudents() {
    students.add(new Student("Shaggy", 3));
    students.add(new Student("Lacy", 2));
    students.add(new Student("Roger", 10));
    students.add(new Student("Tommy", 3));
    students.add(new Student("Tammy", 1));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    loadStudents();

    Collections.sort(students, new Student(null, 0));
    System.out.println(" ");
    for (Student s : students) {
        System.out.print(s.getName() + ", " + s.getGrade() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to implement the grade and name comparison in the compare method. Something like:

```
@Override
public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) 
{
    int result = o1.grade - o2.grade;

    return (result != 0) ? result : o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
}
```

Another option is to create a `Comparator` for each property. Then you can mix and match Comparators using the [Group Comparator](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/group-comparator/).